# How do I implement secure authentication using xml-rpc in python?

Tags: python, web-services, authentication, xml-rpc

I have a basic `xml-rpc` web service service running.
What is the simplest way(I'm a newbie) to implement secure authentication?

I just need some direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could checkout [This code for a simple XML-RPC server over HTTPS](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496786-simple-xml-rpc-server-over-https/). Authentication can work in any way you wish ... they could authenticate with some credentials and you provide a cookie for the rest of the session.

The [Python docs for xmlrpc](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) include details of using the HTTP 'Authorization' header for passing in credentials.

[Here is some code that uses **Twisted**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/526625-twisted-xml-rpc-server-with-basic-http-authenticat/) to implement a xmlrpc auth mechanism, which could easily use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

[This guy has written a HTTPS XML-RPC setup with authorization](http://www.etopian.com/portfolio/https-python-xmlrpc-server-w-authentication) which you can download.
There are tons of resources, and ways of doing this which are easily googleable. This all depends on if you are using mod_wsgi for example, or writing a standalone server using Twisted.

Bottom line:

a) Use SSL for communication
b) Use the HTTP authorization mechanism